# Adding integers until a negative is encountered

Tags: java, file-io, while-loop

Good day! Here is a code that should add the integers from a binary file until a negative number is encountered.

```
n = inputStream.readInt();
while (n>=0) {
    n=m;
    m++;
    n = inputStream.readInt();
}
System.out.println("Sum: "+m);
```

However, when I input 1, 2, 3, it outputs 3 as the sum. Same thing with 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, it outputs 5. I know there is something wrong with my while loop and I just can't figure it out. Please help me figure out what's wrong. Forgive me, I'm new in programming and I'm still learning. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

```
n = inputStream.readInt();
while (n>=0) {
    m += n;
    n = inputStream.readInt();
}
System.out.println("Sum: " + m);
```

You were only adding the number of numbers, not the sum of numbers.

Comment: I just realized that. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your code just counts the number of iterations of the while loop. You are incrementing m on every iterations and at the end you just display the same m value.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Sum: " + m);
```

just displays the final result even though it will be displaying all the other outputs in fraction of a second.

And also the

```
System.out.println("Sum: " + m);
```

shoud be inside the while loop.

In java GUI you can do the same with

```
jTextArea1.setText(jTextArea1.getText()+m); //where jTextArea1 is the component to display the text.
```